# Ways around impredictive polymorphism

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, impredicativetypes

I'm new to some of the more complicated type constructs in Haskell, and have been messing around. I'm currently stuck trying to get a function that I think should work to type check.

Take the following code as an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class X a where
  data Y a
  z :: Y a -> Int

data D1 = D1
instance X D1 where
  data Y D1 = YD1
  z _ = 1

data D2 = D2
instance X D2 where
  data Y D2 = YD2
  z _ = 2

sumZ :: X a => [Y a] -> Int
sumZ = foldl' sumFn 0
  where sumFn = flip ((+) . z)
```

I want `a = sumZ [YD1, YD2]` to type check. This (obviously) doesn't work since the `a` type variable gets fixed with the first `YD1`.

I understand enough to know that I should probably use higher ranked types here, so I tried this:

```
sumZ' :: [(forall a. X a => Y a)] -> Int
sumZ' = foldl' sumFn 0
  where sumFn = flip ((+) . z)
```

But, when I try and compile it I run into "impredicative polymorphism":

```
     • Illegal polymorphic type: forall a. X a => Y a
       GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism
     • In the type signature: sumZ' :: [(forall a. X a => Y a)] -> Int
    |
 48 | sumZ' :: [(forall a. X a => Y a)] -> Int
    |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After doing a bit of reading, I see that the conventional solution is to wrap the value in a `newtype` to skirt around the impredicative polymorphism.

```
newtype Wrap = Wrap { unWrap :: forall a. X a => Y a }

sumZ'' :: [Wrap] -> Int
sumZ'' = foldl' sumFn 0
  where
    sumFn acc (Wrap v) = acc + (z v)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work either. Compilation fails with this message:

```
     • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘z’
       prevents the constraint ‘(X a0)’ from being solved.
       Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
       These potential instances exist:
         instance X D1
           -- Defined at ...
         instance X D2
           -- Defined at ...
     • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘(z v)’
       In the expression: acc + (z v)
       In an equation for ‘sumFn’: sumFn acc (Wrap v) = acc + (z v)
    |
 64 |     sumFn acc (Wrap v) = acc + (z v)
    |                                 ^^^
```

Finally, my question(s):

1. Why doesn't the standard "wrapping" technique work in this case? When inspecting the type of `v` I see that it has the type `forall a. X a => Y a`, to me this seems like it should work.
2. How can I get the `a = sumZ [YD1, YD2]` to work? Am I going about this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that `v :: forall a. X a => Y a` is exactly why applying `z` doesn't work.

That `forall` in there means that `v` can be of any type, you choose which one. To illustrate, compare to this:

```
empty :: forall a. [a]
empty = []
```

There value `empty` can be of any type, the consumer chooses which type. That's what `forall` means here. I hope this much is obvious.

And so it is with your value `v`: it can be of any type, you choose which. But in your code you don't choose a type: you're applying `z`, which itself can work with any type, and so the type of `v` remains unchosen. This is exactly what the compiler is telling you when it complains about the "ambiguous type variable a0".

To make this work, you should put the `forall` *on the other side of `Wrap`*:

```
data Wrap = forall a. X a => Wrap (Y a)
```

(you'll need to enable the `GADTs` extension for this to be allowed)

This way, whoever constructs a `Wrap` has to choose the specific type `a`. And on the other side, when you do pattern matching, you get the type `a` that was chosen by whoever constructed the value.

Comment: I think you mean `newtype Wrap =`? Worth noting that your example is using `ExistentialQuantification` syntax, which can also be written as `data Wrap where Wrap :: forall a. X a => Y a -> Wrap` using `GADTs` (the `forall a.` being optional).

Comment: @JonPurdy Fixed `newtype`, thank you for the catch. The OP was already using `forall`, so I assumed that `ExistentialQuantification` was already enabled. But `GADTs` is still necessary for this to work (if memory serves), regardless of the syntax used.

Comment: I think you actually don’t mean `newtype Wrap =` but rather mean `data Wrap =`! A newtype is, by definition, representationally equivalent to its underlying type, but an existentially quantified type with a dictionary packed inside it is not, since it also has to store the dictionary. Therefore, you can’t use existential quantification over constraints with newtypes.